# "Warrior" in Hangul for shirts and other things

Tags: hangul, korean-to-english

I was wondering how I could put "Warrior" on a shirt that would be the correct syntax and grammar to both English and Korean native speakers. Would "전사" be the correct way to represent the idea? As if to call myself a warrior?

Comment: hello, when someone gives you "the correct answer", it is customary to mark it as correct.  hitting the +1 is optional.  i believe @LifeOnTheMoon has the correct answer, if it is not fully correct, please indicate what the answer is lacking to assist the assister in assisting you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it's correct.

warrior = 전사

I am a warrior = 나는 전사다